# Mongodb aggregate by using input array

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I am struggling to create an aggregate query for my MongoDB database.

here is my input array

`recipients = [1,2,7]`

here is my database collection

```
{
    "chapter": 1,
    "targets": [
      {
        type: 'user',
        recipient: 1
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "chapter": 1,
    "targets": [
      {
        type: 'user',
        recipient: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "chapter": 2,
    "targets": [
      {
        type: 'user',
        recipient: 3
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "chapter": 3,
    "targets": [
      {
        type: 'user',
        recipient: 4
      }
    ]
  },
```

the desired output

```
should be [] because 7 doesn't exist in targets.recipient in the collection
```

here is what I've tried so far

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
      $match: {
        'targets.recipient': { $in: recipients },
      },
    }
])
```

Any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Hi, do you need all of the input array to be present in the document at once, eg. [1,2,7]? if 1,2 matches, the query going to return the document as 1,2 elements are present.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) works is that it returns the document if there's any match between it's value and the array you're passing as a parameter. It looks like in your case you can use `$in` for initial filtering but then you want to return the result only if the result set contains all the values from the input array. In order to achieve it you can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) to get all matching results and then apply [$all](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/index.html):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: { "targets.recipient": { $in: [1,2,7] } }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            docs: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { "docs.targets.recipient": { $all: [1,2,7] } }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oN0Iwdl4h5B)

Answer (score 0):

```
// only matched documents will be shown.
> db.targets.aggregate([ {$match:{"targets.recipient":{$in:[1,2,7]}}}, {$project:{chapter:1,targets:1}} ]).pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f5de14c598d922a1e6eff4d"),
        "chapter" : 1,
        "targets" : [
                {
                        "type" : "user",
                        "recipient" : 1
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f5de14c598d922a1e6eff4e"),
        "chapter" : 1,
        "targets" : [
                {
                        "type" : "user",
                        "recipient" : 2
                }
        ]
}
>
```